# why do i get following error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-blockui

I am usin the plugin JqueryBlockUi to block my psge on ajax calls. It works fine in IE9 and firefox, but not in IE8. I get the following error when the ajax call finishes and try to close the div:
Error:**SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access.** 
this is the code iam using  to block it and unblock it.

```
function uiBlockFunction(){
    $.blockUI({ 
        css: { 
            border: '2px solid #000', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            'border-radius': '5px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '5px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '5px', 
            opacity: 1,

            color: '#000',
            height: '180px',
            width: '500px',
            'font-size': '24px'},
            message: '<img src="../img/AjaxLoader.gif">Processing Request....Please be patient....<br /><img src="../img/infinity-century-logo.png" />' });
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
};
```

Does anybody hknow why this happens?
thank you.

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Is `$.unblockUI` defined when the `$(document).ajaxStop` line runs?  I can imagine a world where you're registering a function that doesn't exist and IE is having a problem trying to invoke undefined although the error isn't really super clear.

Comment: What version of jQuery and what version of blockUI?

Comment: Version 2.66.0-2013.10.09

Answer (score 0):

Is this because of Unnecessary semicolon at the end of your function -

```
            height: '180px',
            width: '500px',
            'font-size': '24px'},
            message: '<img src="../img/AjaxLoader.gif">Processing Request....Please be patient....<br /><img src="../img/infinity-century-logo.png" />' });
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
};
```

change it to -

```
            height: '180px',
            width: '500px',
            'font-size': '24px'},
            message: '<img src="../img/AjaxLoader.gif">Processing Request....Please be patient....<br /><img src="../img/infinity-century-logo.png" />' });
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
}
```

Also check if you have type="text/javascript" in your javascript. IE8 gives error because of this sometime.

Comment: i don't think it is the ajax call. It works fin on other browsers and IE9

Comment: Do u have type="text/javascript" in your javascript ?

Comment: it does not seem to be calling my ajaxStop. I added an alert and nothing showed up.

Comment: Did u try to debug it from IE developer tools ?

Comment: yes this is what i get:
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 

jquery.js, line 3 character 3275

SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. 
jquery.js, line 1 character 15501

Comment: It may also possible that IE7 does not like some of your css values. I see you are passing  - opacity : 1 try to change it to opacity : '1'

Comment: the debug on IE tell me there is an issues below
1ST Error
here:t.appendChild(e)->Unexpected call to method or property access. then one more error:(e.execScript||function(t)
2ndError
{e.eval.call(e,t)})(t)->SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.